# Save data in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, save, append

I am trying to save a variable in .mat format and update and APPEND the NEW contents of THIS variable each time a loop is finished to avoid memory blow up. I have searched a bit and think the best way is structures. But still think there should be an straight way to do that. Anybody can give me an example to how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [matfile](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/matfile.html) to write without loading the file.